# Is it possible to copy website? I need to take design from my friend's website but we want to try this way. Is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, web, copy

I want to copy my friend's website but change language and some details. We are working on wordpress. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Can you tell how to do it?

Comment: So many hits when googling. Did you even try? There are different ways of doing it. Don't know if it works or not, but I would just try to copy the wordpress folder, put it on a wamp server and go from there

Answer (score 1):

The "WordPress" native way would be to :

1. copy all files (via FTP).
2. copy the db (using phpmyadmin or your cPanel) take a look at : https://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database
3. re-import everything in your hosting (files via FTP and DB via phpmyadmin or cPanel.

Another method would be using a dedicated WP plugin such as :
https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/

Don't forget after re-importing the website you will have to change all configuration relative to the URL of the first installation. I recommend you to read : https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress